# Different responses from RPC endpoint when validating same transaction multiple times with Solana Pay JS SDK

Tags: rpc, solana-pay

I have some questions regarding an error when validating transfers. I am using @solana/pay v0.2.0 and @solana/web v1.48.0 JS packages.

First, I find the transaction signature with the `findReference` function, after which I use the `validateTransfer` to check the transfer. The problem I'm facing is that, using the same transaction reference, sometimes I receive a null response from the `connection.getTransaction(signature, options)` call inside the `validateTransfer` function:

```
Status: 200
Data: Object {
  jsonrpc: 2.0,
  result: null,
  id: fa82ccd5-b081-4e42-8b9e-228d97c8fbd4
}
```

which results in an exception being thrown.

However, sometimes it returns the correct response showing a confirmed transaction. The transaction is definitely confirmed as you can see here: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/zJ5vwZjTM54ByjHGR9cXuv2upp7sbDgyErMzd6CB4asyemGuPqeqCgpwzkvrGjqTdwmnPHDUyaTscAGB334HNRu

Has anyone faced this problem? Would this be a question to ask the RPC node provider i use (GenesysGo) ?
thanks!